# Thunar on ubunto one folder icon incorrect

Tags: ubuntu, icons, directory

using Thunar on ubuntu and for some reason one folder has wrong icon.  All other folder icons look good.  Is there a way to correct the bad folder?

Answer (score 0):

rename the folder and then rename it back solves the problem